# Why won't my structure block work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Structure blocks can move structures in-between worlds, right? If so, why does it not work? It says that a certain structure is not available. It's a big build and it took me hours in a void world, and it would take me a long time to build it again.

Answer (score 4):

Structures are saved into **.minecraft/saves/your_save/generated/minecraft/structures**. Simply copy the .nbt files from the structures folder from your original save and paste them into the structures folder of your new save. You might have to create **/generated/minecraft/structures** manually.